# MySQL lock issue

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, drupal-7, apache2

I was experiencing some timeout issues on my Drupal site so I added a max_allowed_packet setting as the last line of the my.cnf file on my Linux server as shown below:

```
.
.
.
!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
!includedir /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/

max_allowed_packet = 200M
```

Shortly afterwards I began experiencing some PDOException errors.

> PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory in lock_may_be_available() (line 167 of /var/www/barnabas/docroot/includes/lock.inc).

So far I have struggled to eliminate the problem.

Comment: I'm not using Drupal myself, but I guess this means that your mySQL database is locking tables, because it runs som heavy queries. To answer your question, we need to know: Why did you have to raise your max_allowed_packet?

Comment: @PeterBechP: I raised it after experiencing problems loading some pages. I googled and found a post where a similar issue was solved by increasing the max_allowed_packet